# How to access object from Inherits model in user control in ASPX markup code

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I use a user control in a Web Forms project. This is a legacy project, but we have taken a lot of inspiration from ASP.NET MVC, and included this in our project.

I embed a user control, but instead of the old "usercontrol-can-do-everything", we more use them as partials and give them a viewmodel.

However, I have a problem accessing my values from my "viewmodel" in the code. Let me show some code and I will explain problem.

**The control definition**:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Saxo.Websites.Shop.Web.PartialControl`1[[Saxo.Websites.Shop.Models.Recommendations.RecommendationsViewModel]]" %>
```

**My "view model"**:

```
 public class RecommendationsViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Placement> Placements { get; set; }

        public RecommendationsViewModel()
        {
            this.Placements = new Dictionary<string, Placement>();
        }
    }

    public class Placement
    {
        public Placement(string divid, string title):this(divid,title,6)
        {

        }

        public Placement(string divid, string title, int count)
        {
            this.DivId = divid;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Count = count;
        }
        public string DivId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

**My partialcontrol file:**

```
 public class PartialControl<T> : UserControl
    {
        public T Model { get; set; }

        public static string RenderPartial(string path, object model)
        {
            var control = new UserControl();
            try
            {
                control = (UserControl)control.LoadControl(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error loading partial control: " + path, ex);
            }            

            var prop = control.GetType().GetProperty("Model");
            if (prop == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(control.GetType().FullName + " does not implement Property 'Model'");
            }


            try
            {
                prop.SetValue(control, model, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error setting model on : " + control.GetType().FullName);
            }


            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        control.RenderControl(hw);

                        return sw.ToString();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Error Rendering Partial Control: " + control.GetType().FullName, ex);

                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to do the following in my markup:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
var test = '<%= Model.Placements["key_in_my_dictionary"].Title %>';
</script>
```

I also tried variants like `<%` and `<%#`.

However, I get this error:

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException: D:\Git\Saxo\Saxo.Websites.Base\src\Saxo.Website.Base\Views\Recommendations\_PageRecommendations.ascx(38): error BC30203: Identifier expected.
```

But I can do the following with success:

```
   <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    var test = '<%= Model.Placements.Count %>';
    </script>
```

Therefore, my question is: how do I write my markup so my JS variable test gets the titles value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it can be worked around by added some getter (so that it does not get those '[' and ']') as follows:

```
public class RecommendationsViewModel
{
     // ...
     public Placement GetPlacement(string name) { return Placements[name]; }
     // ...
}
```

and later in ascx:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    var test = '<%= Model.GetPlacement("name") %>';
</script>
```

Or probably the following would help in ascx:

```
<script runat=server>
  Response.Write("<script charset=\"utf-8\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
  Response.Write("var test = " + Model.Placements["key_in_my_dictionary"].Title);
  Response.Write("<\/script>");
</script>
```

Comment: That would work, only issue is the way it is implemented, is there is no code-behind in the user control. It turned out the error was caused by my frontend was VB.NET and not C# (wtf? :D ). But I will mark your answer as the answer, as it is the best way to do it for future references when people find it through Google.